# Issues in accessing google play services classes using java reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, google-play-services

I'm trying to access Google Play Services classes using java reflection approach like this:

```
Class<?> adIdClientClass;
    try {
        adIdClientClass = Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient");
        Method getAdvertisingIdInfoMethod = adIdClientClass.getDeclaredMethod("getAdvertisingIdInfo", Context.class);
        Object o = getAdvertisingIdInfoMethod.invoke(null, this);
        System.out.println(o);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But, it complaints about not having source of the classes that I'm calling using reflection. Here is the screen shot:
[image]

So there is no way executing google play services classes with reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was just the Eclipse issue. I tried in IntelliJ and it works okay.